# Prolog syntax and predicate logic

Tags: prolog

I have 2 exception at point (*THIS-RTE*) and  (*Other-RTE*) i can not manage to fix it can any1 give me a hint about what am i doing wrong, because I'm pretty sure i mess something up. Thanks

```
decomp([],[],0,0).
decomp([E|T],R,P,I):-
    0 is mod(E,2),
    decomp(T,R1,P1,I),
    R is [E|R1],    %**(*THIS-RTE*)** ERROR: is/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[2|_G7167]' ("x" must hold one character)
    P is 1 + P1.
decomp([E|T],R,P,I):-
    not(0 is mod(E,2)),
    decomp(T,R1,P,I1),
    R is append(E,R1,R), %**(*Other-RTE*)** ERROR: d:/../../../../lab1a.pro:47: evaluable `append(_G5550,_G5551,_G5552)' does not exist, but my clause is right ther
    I is 1 + I1.

append(E,[],[E]).
append(E,[A|St],[A|Et]):-
    append(E,St,Et).
```

Comment: `is` is for arithmetic evaluation of the right hand expression and assignment to the variable on the left. Not for general assignment or unification. So, `R is [E|R1]` (arithmetic evaluation assignemtn) should be `R = [E|R1]` (unify). Also, prolog predicates aren't functions that return values, so `R is append(E,R1,R)` is wrong, as @dasblinkenlight shows in his answer. And, as he points out, the `R = [E|R1]` unification can more conveniently be handled in the header of the rule.

Comment: Your definition of append is problematic. Commonly `append([a],[b],[a,b])` is true.  Use another name.

Comment: Ps in swi prolog, if you overreide a definition in a file and you load it, it will use that definition not the one from the default libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off:

- `R is append(E,R1,R)` should be simply `append(E,R1,R)` because you are passing `R`
- `R is [E|R1]` should go directly into the header of the rule

The result should look like this:

```
decomp([],[],0,0).
decomp([E|T], [E|R1], P, I):-
    0 is E mod 2,
    decomp(T,R1,P1,I),
    P is 1 + P1.
decomp([E|T],R,P,I):-
    1 is E mod 2,
    decomp(T,R1,P,I1),
    append(E,R1,R),
    I is 1 + I1.
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/1ZIVWF)

Comment: @false With only two values of `mod 2` to play with, I think one is as good as the other. I do like `1 is E mod 2` better, though, because it looks more "Prolog"-ish (so I fixed the invocation of `mod/2` in the other clause to match that syntax, too :)

Comment: In any case the opposite of a general`Expr =\= 0` is not `0 is Expr` but `0 =:= Expr`. Because `0 =:= 0.0`